# R studio server browser freezes upon login

Tags: r, linux, rstudio-server

I have been working on my R studio session hosted by a Linux server and recently, ran a piece of code that was taking way too long to execute and I decided to kill it.
Here is the sequence of steps that I took - none of them helped me restore the health of my session.

1) Hit the stop button on R studio and be patient.

2) Ssh into my Linux server and ran the following command to kill all the processes running with my userid

killall -u myuserid

3) Removed the.RData,.Renviron,.Rhistory files from my workspace.

4) Ran the following R command via the Linux server for garbage collection

gc(reset=TRUE)

4) Restarted the entire Linux server.

I am running out of ideas and would really appreciate any other suggestions before I take more drastic steps like revoking access and granting it again(not sure if that would be the right fix)

Note: The browser window freezes every time I login, and it happens only for my R studio session, the rest of the users in the same network have no issues.

Comment: rstudio is probably trying to reload your session data...just delete your .rstudio folder (this will delete your preferences, fyi) using `sudo rm -R ~/.rstudio`. if this doesn't work, kill the rstudio server and restart it. it's been awhile since this has happened to me, but if i remember correctly doing one (or both) of those things always fixed that issue for me.

Comment: That woked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem - Rstudio-serverfreezing. I think it was a network problem since I couldn't receive any response from calling "~~~~~~.cache.js". In this case, you can find out "~~~~~~~~~.cache.js" no response with pushing  key before you click log-in button.

Anyway, here is my way.

1. Reset your Network with following orders
   you can insert these into cmd terminal as an admin mode.

netsh winsock reset

netsh int ip reset

2. Reboot
3. The IP information may be erased. So if you're using fixed IP address, fill the blanks with as-is IP address.

That's all.
You may follow this way to recover the connection.